# Bootstrap navbar list items overflowing with resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the newest version of Bootstrap, but not sure where to start fixing an issue with the navbar. The navbar looks right up until I decrease the width of the browser. The rest of bootstrap's components look fine with a resize, but the list items of the navbar get moved into a weird order. I looked into collapsing, but I think this may be an issue just of padding/width. I haven't made any edits to Bootstrap css. Any places to start?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img alt="Logo" src="./html/Images/logo.png" height="20" />
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">My Navbar</a>
                        <li><a href="./html/page1.html">List item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./html/page2.html">List item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./html/page3.html">List item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y6k4jvv5/3/

Comment: It's not the issue entirely, but you are missing a <ul> or <ol> container tag for your <li>'s.

Comment: Only `li` tags can be direct childs of `ul` and `ol` tags. So your `a` tags must be inside `li`

Answer (score 0):

add li tags around the two a tags and add css for the li to float left

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
                   <li><a  href="#">
                        <img alt="Logo" src="./html/Images/logo.png" height="20" />
                       </a></li>
                   <li><a  href="./index.html">My Navbar</a></li>

                        <li><a href="./html/page1.html">List item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./html/page2.html">List item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./html/page3.html">List item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
li {
   float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y6k4jvv5/4/